# VB.Net Timer Hanging Window

Tags: vb.net, timer, system.thread

I am trying to use the System.Threading class to create a timer which will not prevent the Form from repainting with results or hanging:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module TimerExample

    Private TimerCallback As TimerCallback = New TimerCallback(AddressOf TimerTask)

    Sub Main()
        Dim Timer As Timer = New Timer(TimerCallback, Nothing, 0, 1000)
        Console.WriteLine("Timer has started.")
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to stop the timer...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimerTask(state As Object)
        Console.WriteLine("Timer task executed at: " & DateTime.Now)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Am I doing something incorrect?

From my understanding this must be done with the Threading class so that the code runs in a background thread, however it still seems to be hanging the window

Comment: You cannot have `Console.ReadLine()` in a Form. If you're trying to port a Console app to WinForms, remove all closed loops, use events instead to handle input -- This Timer is most probably not needed. Use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class. There's also nothing related to interactions with Forms here

Comment: [thread.sleep()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-7.0) will probably accomplish this, however I don't know that you should accomplish this. Sounds like you've got a bigger problem that you're trying to bandaid with this

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just how you're trying to achieve it. If we know the end, we can explain the best means to that end. Using that type of `Timer` in a WinForms app is almost certainly a bad idea. There are two other types of `Timer`, one or the other of which would be better if you actually need a timer. If you don't, you might use a `BackgroundWorker` or perhaps using asynchronous methods would be best. We can't know because we don't know what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of using System.Timers.
Timer throw ElapsedEventArgs each timer.interval mS. it can be started or stopped at any time.

```
Imports System.Timers

Module TimerExample

    Sub Main()
        Dim mytimer As New System.Timers.Timer
        AddHandler mytimer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf MyTimerElapsed)
        mytimer.Interval = 1000
        mytimer.Start()
        Console.WriteLine("Timer has started.")
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to stop the timer...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub MyTimerElapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Timer task executed at: " & DateTime.Now)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` is a threaded Timer, which BTW, uses `System.Threading.Timer` under the hood. Its event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread